# Not empty geometry having blank text

Tags: qgis, geojson, geometry, postgis-2.0

i'm having problem with geometry column, for some rows i have geometry with blank text, this query will describe more the problem :

```
select geom, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom), ST_Isvalid(geom), ST_IsEmpty(geom) from polygons
```

[image]

so the rows do not have empty geom but i can see their geometries using qgis.

any help to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a feature in pgadmin/PostGIS - it won't show geometry column values if they are too long. It's mentioned in the PostGIS manual http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/PostGIS_FAQ.html#pgadmin_shows_no_data_in_geom

Comment: Yes , one of the features that has this problem have 17200 vertex.